# Firewall configuration

Tags: firewall

I unlocked the firewall with a view to enabling it and adding some rules. However, I decided not to add any rules. Ever since I've unlocked however, I'm constantly getting pop-ups asking me to authenticate the root user so the firewall settings can be altered. This happens every few minutes, irrespective whether the firewall is disabled or enabled. What's the best way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Have you checked your journal to see what packages might be causing this?  Something like `journalctl --follow`?